Setting Custom Property in customer using APi in Magento
I'm passing a custom property value using an API. The problem is that I am sending "Device Registration" as the origin ( custom property ) but the value that is being set in as "D365FO" why is this happening I'm not sure
{
    "customer": {
        "email": "test2@yahoo.com",
        "firstname": "Hoor",
        "lastname": "Iqbal",
        "store_id": 1,
        "website_id": 1,
        "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "origin",
            "value": "Device registration"
        }
            ]
    },
    "password": "Test@hoor28"
    
}


and this is the response
{
    "id": 40159,
    "group_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2024-07-05 13:24:37",
    "updated_at": "2024-07-05 13:24:37",
    "created_in": "Hookah-Shisha",
    "email": "test2@yahoo.com",
    "firstname": "Hoor",
    "lastname": "Iqbal",
    "store_id": 1,
    "website_id": 1,
    "addresses": [],
    "disable_auto_group_change": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
        "company_attributes": {
            "customer_id": 40159,
            "company_id": 0,
            "status": 1
        },
        "is_subscribed": false
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "yotpo_force_cart_reload",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "age_verification_override",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "is_ageverified",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "migrate_customer",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "is_sales_verified",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "yotpo_accepts_sms_marketing",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "origin",
            "value": "D365FO"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "update_by",
            "value": "Magento"
        }
    ]
}



If that solution works for you, do accept answer as well, might helpful others if accepted.

what is the type of origin attribute?
if its select type you have to provide its value not the label
attach image might help, below you are providing Device registration not its value you need to add value e.g 12345 to select registered

